# Terminal and iTerm2: same profile ANSI colors look differently

Tags: terminal, osx-elcapitan

I've configured iTerm2's profile to match colors of the Pro profile in Terminal app shipped with OS X El Captain. Despite this I can clearly see some colors displayed differently:

[image: two terminal windows showing different colors]

Why does this happen? What other setting did I miss? Exported profile from iTerm2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Ansi 0 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 1 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.60000002384185791</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 10 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.85098040103912354</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 11 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.89803922176361084</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.89803922176361084</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 12 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 13 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.89803922176361084</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.89803922176361084</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 14 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.89803922176361084</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.89803922176361084</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 15 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.89803922176361084</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.89803922176361084</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.89803922176361084</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 2 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.65098041296005249</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 3 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.60000002384185791</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.60000002384185791</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 4 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.85894733667373657</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.034443430602550507</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.12391651421785355</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 5 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.69803923368453979</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.69803923368453979</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 6 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.69803923368453979</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.65098041296005249</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 7 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.74901962280273438</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.74901962280273438</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.74901962280273438</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 8 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.40000000596046448</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.40000000596046448</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.40000000596046448</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Ansi 9 Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.89803922176361084</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Background Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Bold Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Cursor Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.30196079611778259</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.30196079611778259</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.30196079611778259</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Cursor Text Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>1</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Foreground Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.94901961088180542</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.94901961088180542</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.94901961088180542</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Selected Text Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.0</real>
    </dict>
    <key>Selection Color</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Blue Component</key>
        <real>0.25490197539329529</real>
        <key>Green Component</key>
        <real>0.25490197539329529</real>
        <key>Red Component</key>
        <real>0.25490197539329529</real>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: The colors in the Iterm2 window are brighter than those in Terminal.  But you did not say how you replicated the colors.

Comment: I've opened iTerm2's profile settings and made sure that RGB values are the same for both normal and bright ANSI colors as in Terminal's profile settings. I've also made sure other settings such as fonts, window transparency etc are the same.

Comment: When I export Terminal's settings, the color information is encoded - no RGB at all.

Comment: I didn't export them, because I didn't find export operation in Terminal's settings. Instead I opened Terminal's settings and copied all RGB information manually to the iTerm2's settings. Then I exported the profile from iTerm2 to inline it into my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Terminal and iTerm have palettes for "bright" and "normal" colors. Both also have a "Draw bold text in bright colors" that have opposite defaults. On my system the defaults appear to be the following:

**Terminal Defaults:**

[image]

**iTerm Defaults:**

[image: Defaults]

I'm not sure if the text in question is bolded or not, but making sure this setting is consistent between both applications may resolve the issue.

**EDIT:** Also check the contrast option under profiles > colors

[image]

Comment: This is not a correct answer, but I it made me explore more until I have found "Minimal contrast" option in iTerm2. After adjusting it and playing with normal blue color params, I've managed to get it to match Terminal's profile. I'll mark it as an answer and grant the bonus, but please edit your answer to include the fact that one needs to adjust "Minimal contrast" option.

Comment: This is apparently surprisingly still valid, do you happen to have the value for "minimum contrast" that makes iTerm2 match Terminal.app's color rendering? I'm finding values of around 30-40 seem to provide an almost exact match.